# Applying access query to all the fields in a access table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a simple difference query in MS access which takes the difference of two columns from a table. For example column 'A' is constant here but column 'B' is dynamic.

What i require is that 'B' column should change and user can take the difference against any column in the table. Basically user should be able to have difference between A:B, A:C, A:D.....A:N.
Will i have to write separate queries for all the fields?

Answer (score 1):

One option may be to modify the SQL of the query on the fly, based on user selection.

Create a form with a combo box, set the Row Source Type to "Value List", and set the Row Source to be the names of the fields B through to N, separated by semi-colons (for example `Total2;Total3;Total4`).

Create the query that calculates the difference between fields A and B, and save that.

Finally, create a command button that has the following code in the OnClick event:

```
Dim strSQL as String
If Not IsNull(Me!cboSelect) Then
    strSQL="SELECT [Total1]-[" & Me!cboSelect & "] AS DifferenceTotal " _
        & " FROM tblDifference;"
    CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryDifference").SQL=strSQL
End If
```

However, it may be that your database design needs to be looked at, as it seems that you may be treating the table as a spreadsheet.

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for responding. However i am getting an error "MS access cannot find field 'cboselect' referred in your expression". Also Is there a way to do this at one go? i mean have the differences against all fields in one table or query apart from having user specific fields as well?

Comment: cboSelect is the name of the combo box that holds the list of fields B through to N.